# Render data offscreen in UIView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-animation

How would I go about drawing a view offscreen in order to perform some calculation before the view's draw is actually done? Can this be done by drawing to a temporary layer?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not getting your exact problem... But you can use

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

this method will be called every time before your view will appear on the screen... you can do the calculation and make some changes here before view appear on the screen...

Comment: FYI viewwillappear is a method on uiviewcontroller and not uiview